# Watin support for IE 9 - Part 2 (Specific)

Tags: watin, internet-explorer-9

**Watin Runtime Version: v2.0.50727
Browser: IE 9**

**I have found a specific issue:**
BaseIEController.IE.Element(fieldname).Exists throws an Exception as under:
"It's not possible to find the element because no element finder is available."

The fieldname here is a Regex for a link, a simple Regex where the Link's Id is passed. 
This works with IE 8.

I cannot use the Final Release of Watin 2.0 since the LogonHandler is not complete (not fully functional as mentioned in the Release Document. I have tried testing it as well).

Any idea on how I can get this Element thingy to work??

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0):

Today I have upgraded to IE9 on my windows 2008 system and run all the 745 WatiN 2.x unittests and found no issues (accept for one dialog handling the javascript::return dialog fired by onbeforeunload event).

Let me know if you have more specific info/ code example will help too to reproduce the issue you reported.

Jeroen
Lead dev WatiN

Comment: I had a large content in my reply hence posted it as an answer above. I have also added 2 comments to it. Please see the above post

Comment: Got the latest release of Watin (2.1 I think) and it now works with IE9. I still have issues with accessing the selected item of a dropdown list (raised as a new query). But this query is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. Firstly, Awesome job with Watin :)

I am trying to run the test using VS2008 and IE 9. The goal is to Click a Link but before that I am verifying if the Link is exists. 
The Regex I use for this link is **LnkSignIn = new Regex(".*linkSignIn$");** 
I then use **BaseIEController.IE.Element(fieldname).Exists** where the fieldname is an Attribute Constraint (in this case the Regex). This would return a true or false if the Link is found. If found, I then click the Link. Instead it returns the Error MyTestInitialize threw exception. WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException:  WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException: It's not possible to find the element because no element finder is available.. at WatiN.Core.Element.WaitUntilExistsOrNot(Int32 timeout, Boolean waitUntilExists)
...
This works just fine with IE 8. Further, I noticed that if I change Element to Link, it returns true. But since this is a generic method, I want to keep it as element. Hope this helps. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: Since LogonHandler is not complete in Watin 2 Final Release, I can't use it to run my tests. But interestingly, when I use it, I get the following exception as soon as my test starts: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WatiN.Core, Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

Comment: Btw, With IE8 I can get the LogonHandler to work. I use Watin v2.0.50727 and it seems to be fine. The problem is in using IE 9. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Please edit your initial question to add more information instead of adding an answer.